# How to Create popup window for WordPress using some plugin or php code?

Tags: php

I want to know how to add popup plugin in word press site, actually I am not good at PHP, so I need to know code for popup box and where to place that in home page index.php. I have tried some basic popup code

```
$a=1; 
if ($a==1)
{
$message = 'thank you.';  <SCRIPT>
echo "alert('$message')";  </SCRIPT>
}
```

but i don't know where to exactly place it in the index.php

Comment: For **Popups**, you should look at JavaScript & jQuery. https://jquery.com

Comment: I suggest you use a plugin instead, e.g.https://wordpress.org/plugins/nifty-modal-popup/ Then have a look at their code to see how it's done :)

Comment: Try this plugin http://4nton.com/product/wdes-responsive-popup/, this is free. You download it via button or install via WordPress add plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You should try with Javascript not with php because php is executed at server side and Javascript at client side.

Here is a little example : http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp